# How to make ' i ' vectors

Tags: c++, list, vector, for-loop

Im not sure if you can do this but I want to make a certain amount of vectors which the amount of vector depends on another number. So if the number is 3 I want to make 3 vectors and if its 4 I want to make 4 vectors and so on. Is there a way to do this? maybe using a for loop? or is there a better way to approach this situation.
For my assignment I have to read a text document and display the tables within the document. So the number of vectors I want depends on the number of columns there are. 
If anyone could help that would be great.
thanks

Comment: Or a *list* of vectors, or a *set* of vectors, or a *map* of vectors. It all depends upon how you want to access the collection of vectors.

Answer (score 1):

```
int i = 10;
std::vector<std::vector<int> >(i, std::vector<int>());
```

Answer (score 0):

A vector of vectors is the most obvious answer. You can make a vector of anything (more or less), so a vector of vectors presents no special problems.

```
int i = 10;
std::vector< std::vector<int> > x(i);
```

x is a vector of ten vectors (of ints).